# How to return the data which receive from Axios in Object form

Tags: reactjs, axios, request-promise

```
const Request = axios.create({
baseURL: 'https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/'
});

export const ScenicSpotRequest = async () => Request.get('Tourism/ScenicSpot? 
$top=30&$format=JSON').then(response => response.data);

export async function getScenicSpotRequest() {
try {
      const item = await ScenicSpotRequest();
      // console.log(item);
      return item;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
}
```

The value of return item is a promise. However I want the promise turn to Object which I can use it like getScenicSpotRequest[0].Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` function will always return a `Promise`. A promise that it will give you the result/error whenever it itself gets it.

So if you want to use the data of the Promise you need to make use of `.then()`

For example, wherever  you are using `getScenicSpotRequest()`, make use of `.then` to get the reusult.

```
getScenicSpotRequest().then(res => {
      console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Your explanation is so clear and useful!!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted.